# Combined regex pattern to match beginning and end of string and remove a separator character

Tags: python, regex, regex-group, python-re

I have the following strings:

```
"LP, bar, company LLP, foo, LLP"
"LLP, bar, company LLP, foo, LP"
"LLP,bar, company LLP, foo,LP"  # note the absence of a space after/before comma to be removed
```

I am looking for a regex that takes those inputs and returns the following:

```
"LP bar, company LLP, foo LLP"
"LLP bar, company LLP, foo LP"
"LLP bar, company LLP, foo LP"
```

What I have so fat is this:

```
import re

def fix_broken_entity_names(name):
    """
    LLP, NAME -> LLP NAME
    NAME, LP -> NAME LP
    """
    pattern_end = r'^(LL?P),'
    pattern_beg_1 = r', (LL?P)$'
    pattern_beg_2 = r',(LL?P)$'
    combined = r'|'.join((pattern_beg_1, pattern_beg_2, pattern_end))
    return re.sub(combined, r' \1', name)
```

When I run it tho:

```
>>> fix_broken_entity_names("LP, bar, company LLP, foo,LP")
Out[1]: '  bar, company LLP, foo '
```

I'd be very thankful for any tips or solutions :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use

```py
import re
texts = ["LP, bar, company LLP, foo, LLP","LLP, bar, company LLP, foo, LP","LLP,bar, company LLP, foo,LP"]
for text in texts:
    result = ' '.join(re.sub(r"^(LL?P)\s*,|,\s*(LL?P)$", r" \1\2 ", text).split())
    print("'{}' -> '{}'".format(text, result))
```

Output:

```
'LP, bar, company LLP, foo, LLP' -> 'LP bar, company LLP, foo LLP'
'LLP, bar, company LLP, foo, LP' -> 'LLP bar, company LLP, foo LP'
'LLP,bar, company LLP, foo,LP' -> 'LLP bar, company LLP, foo LP'
```

See a [Python demo](https://ideone.com/BVz8gc). The [regex](https://regex101.com/r/Hrb5P4/1) is `^(LL?P)\s*,|,\s*(LL?P)$`:

- `^(LL?P)\s*,` - start of string, `LLP` or `LP` (Group 1), zero or more whitespaces, comma
- `|` - or
- `,\s*(LL?P)$` - a comma, zero or more whitespaces, `LP` or `LLP` (Group 2) and then of string.

Note the replacement is a concatenation of Group 1 and 2 values enclosed within single spaces, and a post-process step is to remove all leading/trailing whitespace and shrink whitespace inside the string to single spaces.

Comment: It looks like the regex101 demo is preserving too many spaces

Comment: @MonkeyZeus Sure, that is why Python helps here a lot: *a post-process step is to remove all leading/trailing whitespace and shrink whitespace inside the string to single spaces*.

Comment: Oh I see, the use of `.split()`, etc...?

Comment: @MonkeyZeus It is a `" ".join(list_here)` idiom.

Answer (score 1):

Make use of capture groups and reformat it how you wish:

**regex:**

```
([^,\r\n]+) *, *([^,\r\n]+) *, *([^,\r\n]+) *, *([^,\r\n]+) *, *([^,\r\n]+)
```

**replacement**

```
\1 \2, \3, \4 \5
```

https://regex101.com/r/jcEzzy/1/